# Flutter. Execution failed for task ':audioplayer:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, build

I try flutter run --release and getting an error. All the flutter analyze and flutter doctor is giving me the all is fine flags. Can you help me, please?

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audioplayer:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\����\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

     C:\Users\����\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

     C:\Users\����\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.

     C:\Users\����\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\����\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a271e99b6771ad4a84318244d532fb7\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 46s
```

Answer (score 1):

change your  audioplayers dependencies in pubspec.yml

dependencies:
  audioplayers: ^0.15.1